# scrollview with recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

This is the fragment that I put in the viewPager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_own_product_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/profile_bg"
tools:context="fyp.hkust.facet.fragment.OwnProductFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/ownproductlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_product_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus_white_36dp"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple"
    fab:fab_shadow="true" />
```

The following is the activity

**Updated:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/profile_coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


<!-- your content layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:elevation="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/profile_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/profile_bg"
            tools:context="fyp.hkust.facet.activity.ProfileActivity">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:elevation="6dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/app_icon" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile_email"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_button_no_bg"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contextClickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:text="@string/edit_btn_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/font_color_pirmary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_picture"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_edit"
                    android:text="@string/profile_username"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_username"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_picture"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_edit"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/profile_email"
                    android:textColor="@color/profile_email_text_color"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_title" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I make it to let me scroll the whole view instead of scrolling only in the recycler view like instragram? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use NestedScrollview
Instead of scrollview.

You can enable / disable recyclerview's nested scrolling feature according to you need.

Scroll view doesn't support nested scrolling. Where as nested scroll view will give you what you need.

You should try following this hierarchy

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:contentScrim="@color/action_bar"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="right"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_images_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="below will be your elements" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/accent"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you mean android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView?

Comment: So I should disable the recycler view 's scroll and change the scroll view to nested scrollview?

Comment: Yes, it provides nested scrolling.

Comment: No don't disable it. It was just to inform.

Comment: After I change the scrollview become nestedscrollview , it cannot scroll for both view.

Comment: Have you tried following the structure I have suggested?

Comment: Try following above link

Comment: Have you tried that code? Change flags according to your need.

Comment: I still cannot do it =[ but does instragram use CollapsingToolbarLayout? I am just thinking that it is change the scrollview of recycler view to become a whole view scroll

Comment: You can disable those scrolling effects with collapsing bar by setting appropriate flags

Comment: I should include the part that I want to disable when I am scrolling? Do I need to add the nested scrollbar? Thank You

Comment: Nested scroll was suggested just to replace scroll view as recyclerview was there which might cause the problem. Whether to remove or keep depends on the way you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this ,at the end of the xml layout close the ScrollView .Place it below the Relative layout.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profile_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/profile_bg"
        tools:context="fyp.hkust.facet.activity.ProfileActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/app_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile_email"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/border_button_no_bg"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contextClickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:text="@string/edit_btn_text"
                android:textColor="@color/font_color_pirmary" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_picture"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_edit"
                android:text="@string/profile_username"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_username"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_picture"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_edit"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/profile_email"
                android:textColor="@color/profile_email_text_color"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```